# pathExtension is unavailable: Use pathExtension on NSURL instead. Swift 2.0

Tags: ios, xcode, swift, swift2

I get mp3 files from Document Directory, I wrote that pathExtension equals "mp3", in the Swift 1.2 it is working, but in the Swift 2.0 I get the error " 'pathExtension' is unavailable: Use pathExtension on NSURL instead."

```
 func fetchFilesFromFolder() {
        let fileManager = NSFileManager.defaultManager()
        let folderPathURL = fileManager.URLsForDirectory(NSSearchPathDirectory.DocumentDirectory, inDomains: NSSearchPathDomainMask.UserDomainMask)[0]
        if let directoryURLs = try? fileManager.contentsOfDirectoryAtURL(folderPathURL, includingPropertiesForKeys: nil, options: NSDirectoryEnumerationOptions.SkipsHiddenFiles) {
            listOfMP3Files = directoryURLs.map(){ $0.lastPathComponent! }.filter(){ $0.pathExtension == "mp3" } // error is here
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Just change the order: first `filter`, than `map`. Now the method `pathExtension` is applied to the NSURL objects.

```
listOfMP3Files = directoryURLs.filter { $0.pathExtension == "mp3" }.map { $0.lastPathComponent! }
```

You can omit the pair of parentheses after `filter` and `map` using the `trailing closure` rule.

Apple has removed the path related API from `String` to prefer the more suitable `URL`.

Answer (score 14):

Or you can use this extension:

```
extension String {
    var ns: NSString {
        return self as NSString
    }
    var pathExtension: String {
        return ns.pathExtension
    }
    var lastPathComponent: String {
        return ns.lastPathComponent
    }
}
```

Comment: I needed to combine Dharmesh and Leo's approaches to get my extension to work:    `extension String {
  public var url: NSURL {
    return NSURL(fileURLWithPath:self)
  }
  public var stringByDeletingLastPathComponent: String {
    return String(url.URLByDeletingLastPathComponent)
  }
}`

Answer (score 4):

**Xcode 8.3.2 • Swift 3.1**

```
extension String {
    var fileURL: URL {
        return URL(fileURLWithPath: self)
    }
    var pathExtension: String {
        return fileURL.pathExtension
    }
    var lastPathComponent: String {
        return fileURL.lastPathComponent
    }
}
```

Comment: looks very nice indeed but the NSString casting might be less expensive ;-)

Answer (score 4):

Base on this [link](https://forums.developer.apple.com/thread/13580), this extension will help you in many case.

```
extension String {

    var lastPathComponent: String {
        get {
            return (self as NSString).lastPathComponent
        }
    }

    var pathExtension: String {
        get {

            return (self as NSString).pathExtension
        }
    }

    var stringByDeletingLastPathComponent: String {
        get {

            return (self as NSString).stringByDeletingLastPathComponent
        }
    }

    var stringByDeletingPathExtension: String {
        get {

            return (self as NSString).stringByDeletingPathExtension
        }
    }

    var pathComponents: [String] {
        get {

            return (self as NSString).pathComponents
        }
    }

    func stringByAppendingPathComponent(path: String) -> String {

        let nsSt = self as NSString

        return nsSt.stringByAppendingPathComponent(path)
    }

    func stringByAppendingPathExtension(ext: String) -> String? {

        let nsSt = self as NSString

        return nsSt.stringByAppendingPathExtension(ext)
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

I combined Dharmesh and Leo's approaches to get my extension to work:

```
  extension String { 
      public var url: NSURL {
         return NSURL(fileURLWithPath:self)
      }
      public var stringByDeletingLastPathComponent: String {
         return String(url.URLByDeletingLastPathComponent)
      }
 }
```

Answer (score 0):

[Swift Doc 1.2 specs regarding these funcs don't return an optional](http://swiftdoc.org/v1.2/type/String/)

To make it backward compatible to 1.2 in Swift 2.0, do this:

Improve upon @Dharmesh Kheni 's version.

```
extension String {
  var ns: NSString {
    return self as NSString
  }
  var pathExtension: String {
    return ns.pathExtension ?? ""
 }
  var lastPathComponent: String {
    return ns.lastPathComponent ?? ""
   }
}
```